# How to put a layout below other layout in Android

Tags: android, layout

I have this code:

```
RelativeLayout frame = new RelativeLayout(activity);

RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams dateArea = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,90
);                
dateArea.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
RelativeLayout mapLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mapParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    height-120
);

frame.addView(mapLayout,mapParam);
frame.addView(layout, dateArea);
```

I want the Date area align at the bottom and below the map. But it is always align on the top, it is really weird, please show me what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams dateArea = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
90);

dateArea .addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
```

Comment: Wow! you save my day (y). I really appreciate an explain, thank you in advance!

Comment: Happy To Help. Have a good day. You used `FILL_PARENT` so it was taking up the whole screen. Just changed it to `WRAP_CONTENT` so it will acquire space that it actually needs.

Comment: Why it took up the whole screen instead of just fill the width of parent?

Comment: as i guess parent was taking up the screen too

Answer (score 0):

`RelativeLayout` can be used to relatively offset any views against other views.

- you need to define an id in say `res/values/properties.xml` (create a file if such not existing or use any other if you prefer)

  `<resources>
      <item name="layout" type="id"/>
  </resources>`
- then assign this id - `layout.setId(R.id.layout)`
- this way you don't need to get screen height but rather add another rule `mapParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.id.layout)`

Then change your code:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams dateArea = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 90);
dateArea.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
layout.setId(R.id.layout);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mapParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
mapParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.id.layout);
RelativeLayout mapLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

RelativeLayout frame = new RelativeLayout(this);
frame.addView(mapLayout,mapParam);
frame.addView(layout, dateArea);
// TODO Don't forget to add 'frame' or it won't show anything
```